# Position pictures on odd page numbers in MS Word

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, layout

**How do I make pictures appear on odd-numbered pages?**

I am writing a book which contains pictures and tables. I would like to specify that pictures/tables should always appear on the *right* side of the book.

I would like to follow the tradition of odd page numbers on the right. This means that pictures positioned on the right side, are also always positioned on odd numbers, like in the picture below:

[image]

I know that I can anchor the picture to a certain position on the given page, but I don't know if it is possible to specify that the given page should always be odd numbered.

Any ideas?

Comment: this might be helpful: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4ecd89c8-9b50-470b-832c-9e6d6d54a2ae/different-watermarks-on-even-and-odd-pages?forum=word

Comment: This would be relatively easy to do in a page layout software (InDesign or Framemaker for example)